# Inserting and Populating Chart with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My Code uses a data set which has been modified using another script [Calculating Time Difference](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116637/calculate-maximum-time-difference-within-a-time-period-with-max-30-minutes-diffe) and then inserts and populates a Chart with that Data.

Save a Macro enabled WorkBook as Book1.xlsm with a Sheet named Book1.

To setup data values for testing copy the data below and paste it to cell B19 in your Excel Sheet named "Book1". and then Use the Text to Columns Function to Delimit it using spaces. The Code should work fine after that.

> ORIGINAL DATA   DATE    SYNCH DURATION
>   2015/08/01 12:53:02.700     2015/08/01  12:49.002
>   2015/08/01 17:39:57.520     2015/08/01  00:41.600
>   2015/08/02 17:39:39.225     2015/08/02  00:27.198
>   2015/08/03 06:39:59.277     2015/08/03  01:05.600
>   2015/08/03 15:31:18.520     2015/08/03  01:30.599
>   2015/08/04 05:15:04.593     2015/08/04  02:29.799
>   2015/08/05 04:41:48.311     2015/08/05  01:40.199
>   2015/08/06 05:02:02.023     2015/08/06  01:36.199
>   2015/08/07 05:02:06.118     2015/08/07  02:16.998
>   2015/08/07 16:17:51.368     2015/08/07  00:43.401
>   2015/08/08 17:46:32.678     2015/08/08  00:12.999
>   2015/08/09 18:01:26.385     2015/08/09  00:41.598
>   2015/08/10 17:24:19.299     2015/08/10  01:57.797
>   2015/08/11 06:14:12.158     2015/08/11  00:28.999
>   2015/08/11 15:26:39.003     2015/08/11  00:07.202
>   2015/08/12 06:14:14.268     2015/08/12  00:08.600
>   2015/08/12 15:25:52.311     2015/08/12  03:05.599
>   2015/08/13 17:37:10.434     2015/08/13  02:04.598
>   2015/08/14 16:48:52.942     2015/08/14  05:51.401
>   2015/08/15 18:12:55.861     2015/08/15  02:35.601
>   2015/08/16 17:13:59.966     2015/08/16  02:02.600
>   2015/08/17 05:24:38.823     2015/08/17  01:28.400

Paste this code into a Module of the WorkBook. You will get an error if it is pasted into the Sheet Module due to the `Function GetTickCount`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Sub CreateChart()

'    'Disable Screen Updating
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Normally the DataFileFullPath is set using a FilePicker and the DataFileFullPath, DataFileName, SheetName are all generater in another Sub, its just here to help automate the testing
    Dim DataFileFullPath As String
    DataFileFullPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName


    Dim DataFileName As String, BackSlashPostion As Long
    'Finding the start of the File Name with Extension
    'by looking for the first \ from the right in DataFileFullPath, eg Unit 31.csv
    BackSlashPostion = InStrRev(DataFileFullPath, "\")
    DataFileName = Right(DataFileFullPath, Len(DataFileFullPath) - BackSlashPostion)

    Dim SheetName As String, FullStopPostion As Long
    'Finding the start of the File Name without Extension
    'by looking for the first . from the right in DataFileName, eg Unit 31
    FullStopPostion = InStrRev(DataFileName, ".")
    SheetName = Left(DataFileName, FullStopPostion - 1)

    Dim StartTickCount As Long
    StartTickCount = GetTickCount

    Dim DataWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Set DataWorkSheet = Workbooks(DataFileName).Sheets(SheetName)

    With DataWorkSheet

        Dim LastRow As Long, columnIndex As Long, firstRow As Long
        columnIndex = 3 '/ Column "C"
        firstRow = 20
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnIndex).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim DateRange As Range, TimeRange As Range
        'The DataStartRow is set to the ORiginal Time from the T3000
        Set DateRange = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, columnIndex + 1), .Cells(LastRow, columnIndex + 1))
        Set TimeRange = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, columnIndex + 2), .Cells(LastRow, columnIndex + 2))


    End With

    Dim RunningTimeChart As Chart
    Set RunningTimeChart = Workbooks(DataFileName).Charts.Add

    With RunningTimeChart
        'The autodata population of the chart is based on the Active Cell when in serting the Chart
        'By setting the SourceData to a Blank Cell it then clears the content of the Chart
        .SetSourceData (DataWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1))
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        '=============================================================================================
        'Ignore the hiding part, it is just a reference to what happens in another module
        'The original data set havs merged cells, which I hide and then the section below allows multiple data from the saem day

            'Hiding the Rows from row 2 to end of a TimePeriod to prevent them being displayed in the CHart
            'The Chart will display the highest value for a specific date.
            'With the Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale it then displayed everyvalue
            'This leads to there being blank entries in the Chart
            .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale

        '=============================================================================================

        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Values = TimeRange
            .Name = SheetName & " " & "Synch Time"
            .XValues = DateRange
        End With

        .Name = SheetName & " " & "Synch Time Chart"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0.0104166667 ' 15 mins / 50 / 24
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.0006944444 ' 1 mins /60 / 24
        'Moving to the Second Sheet in the DataFileName WorkBook
        .Move After:=Workbooks(DataFileName).Sheets(2)

    End With

    Dim EndTickCount As Long
    EndTickCount = GetTickCount - StartTickCount

    'MsgBox EndTickCount

'    'Enable Screen Updating
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I think I covered most of the basics for this Module, would like some some peer review.

I am busy looking at how QueryPerformanceCounter works to get more accurate timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm very appreciative of the instructions and sample data provided so that the macro ran without me needing to figure it all out. +1 just for that, really.**

Overall, this seems pretty solid. The only thing you might want to do is use some functions for some of the processes if you use them more than once, which I didn't see. Maybe use a function for getting the names of the workbook and sheet so this sub is strictly creating the chart. Otherwise I don't really have anything negative to say. If you're going to keep the timer in the final version I'd put a comment explaining the need for the library.

I'm consistently at `156` for the timer - pretty quick.

Although I did have a COM add-on that had a fatal error every time I ran the macro until I disabled it. I've attached a screenshot (at the end), though I doubt it will be of any use to you. Maybe if you run into anyone experiencing fatal errors.

<s>Maybe I'm missing something because of how you do your FilePicker but (**I'm sure I am**) -</s>

```
Dim DataFileFullPath As String
    DataFileFullPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    Dim DataFileName As String, BackSlashPostion As Long
    'Finding the start of the File Name with Extension
    'by looking for the first \ from the right in DataFileFullPath, eg Unit 31.csv
    BackSlashPostion = InStrRev(DataFileFullPath, "\")
    DataFileName = Right(DataFileFullPath, Len(DataFileFullPath) - BackSlashPostion)
```

could be accomplished with -

```
 DataFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
```

It gives the extension as well. Same goes for the `SheetName`. I'm going to assume you're doing this to closed files or something, but I couldn't *not* mention it.

This comment is awesome -

```
With RunningTimeChart
    'The autodata population of the chart is based on the Active Cell when in serting the Chart
    'By setting the SourceData to a Blank Cell it then clears the content of the Chart
    .SetSourceData (DataWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1))
```

Explaining *why* something is happening - it's great.

---

Screenshot down here so the answer doesn't look like it's a failure.
[image]

Comment: Some great feedback. This `Sub` is part of a sequence of subs which opens an additional Excel Workbook, deletes blank rows, sums up the maximum time difference between entries with a maximum difference of 30 mins and then finally inserts the `Chart` based on the maximum times. One of the subs uses the `FilePicker` to get a FilePath which i then use to get the FileName and SheetName. I added the `DataFileFullPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName` just for the people testing my code. Since being on CR, I use the timer alto. will definitely add the comment.